# Hello, I have Windows Xp and I have install Ubuntu in a second USB harddisk(120Gb)

Tags: system-installation

I have Windows Xp and I have install Ubuntu in a second USB harddisk(120Gb) with "wubi", in this harddisk I have and Windows XP files, after 2 years I see in update Ubuntu this: "no space left on device"...
Version Ubuntu:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

what can I do?c

Comment: Paste the output of df -h command here.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `sudo apt-get clean` in terminal. This will clear cache of package archives you downloaded to install packages thus giving you some space to be able to clear your disk better without having apps crashing because of lack of disk space.